# Creating a local git server in Windows XP

Tags: git, version-control, windows-xp

I need to implement version control for the project I am currently working on.

I have a Windows XP SP2 VM which is where I should set the server, which would be accessed by another Windows XP machine.

My question is, how do I set the server?

I know that the "best" choice would be to actually ditch XP for the server and just install Linux on a VM and run gitolite or anything of that sort, but since the likeliness of that happening is extremely low, what are my options here?

Gitstack failed on me since XP is not supported (according to their page. I get a DLL error when starting gitstack).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on what you expect from your server, in particular whether you just want to serve repositories, or if you want additional tools, like a web-based interface.

Comment: A web interface would be nice, but it isn't critical. Serving repos would be the priority here.

Comment: Using an SSH server and bare repositories should work (more or less as it would on Linux). Perhaps this might help: http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/wiki/HOWTO_CentralServerWindowsXP

Comment: thank you, I am looking into it now!

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [GitStack](http://gitstack.com/).

Comment: Tried it, but it didn't work. I don't think XP is supported by GitStack (and I cannot upgrade the VM)..

Comment: What's the exact error of GitStack on XP? We dropped the support because we could not open the firewall automatically. However, it should be possible to make it work. -- I am the GitStack owner.

Comment: I have Gitstack working on an nLite'd build of XP SP3 VM hosted on Azure. 2 weeks in, no issues so far.